# How do you sync your Outlook contacts with Gmail?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, sync, microsoft-outlook-2007

I would like to sync the contacts of Microsoft Outlook 2007 with the contacts of my GMail account. Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the free Google tool [Google Apps Sync for Microsoft Outlook](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156587) :

> Google Apps Sync synchronizes nearly
>   all of your personal contact
>   information between Outlook and the
>   Google Apps interface so you can reach
>   colleagues, family, and other contacts
>   from either interface.

You can download it from [here](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gappssync).

[image]

You may also use file export and import, as described in:
[Merge your Outlook and Gmail contacts](http://news.cnet.com/8301-13880_3-10017934-68.html)

Comment: Unfortunately it only seems to work with with the Premier or EDU edition of Google Apps: "Requires Google Apps Premier or EDU Edition"

Comment: There was also the 2nd part to my answer that could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

[OggSync](http://oggsync.com/)

The basic version is free and it supports [features](http://oggsync.com/index.php/documentation-for-outlook-add-in/detailed-feature-chart-for-outlook/) like Outlook's color categories.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the lack of a decent cheap/free sync option for years until I stumbled across [CalDav Synchronizer](https://caldavsynchronizer.org/).

I've been using it for over a couple of years now and it pretty much does everything I need it to including syncing Google Contacts and Google Calendar (which I use on my Android phone) with MS Outlook on my PC and Laptop.

Best of all it's Open Source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a freeware **Contacts Sync** to [Sync your Outlook Contacts with Gmail](http://www.pppindia.com/contacts-sync)
And yes it works with your regular Gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

**This post relates those that need to sync only part of the outlook contacts to gmail. The easiest way to do this is by using Outlook categories.**

I wanted to chime in that I've done quite a bit of research and, AFAIK, there is currently no free option to **sync outlook contacts filtered by categories** with gmail.

The commonly mentioned Go Contact Sync advertises that it allows for synchronizing categories, but it does not properly support categories. Over a year ago, I inquired with the developer WHERE to work with said functionality and did not get a reply.

Alternative #1: You can, however, move all the contacts from desired categories into a different contacts folder in outlook, then sync that secondary contact folder only using commonly available methods, including free ones.

Alternative #2: You supposedly can **sync outlook contacts filtered by categories** with an android device via http://www.android-sync.com/. Your android device, in turn, will take care of syncing with your gmail account. I have not been able to get this software to sync categories properly, but it IS beta and it does do everything else well.

Answer (score 0):

As well there is tool calling Outlook4Gmail. It's freeware in basic version but it's enough to sync your contacts.