# Keep outlook and Gmail contacts in Sync

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, sync, contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you sync your Outlook contacts with Gmail?](https://superuser.com/questions/70292/how-do-you-sync-your-outlook-contacts-with-gmail)

What free (or better, open source) applications do you know of to keep outlook and Gmail contacts in sync? I need my outlook and Gmail accounts to be in sync, since my phone can only connect to Gmail...

I've tried `GO Contact Sync`, but it won't preserve categories, and I also tried  `Gcontactsynch`but it seems outdated. `Google Apps Sync` is only for paying users, and `Chapura` too.

Any application out there that does great sync between gmail and outlook? Thanks!

CFP.

Answer (score 0):

Go Contact Sync does support categories, maybe you misconfigured it of used an outdated version.

Download it from here:
http://www.webgear.co.nz/Products/GOContactSync.aspx

And use this tutorial (Scroll down to contacts sync):
http://knokio.com/guide/sync-gmail-contacts-and-google-calendar-with-outlook/

Comment: It doesn't handle categories well at all: suppose I have 2 categories a and B, and a contact belonging to both. Then in gmail I end with 3 categories, A, B, and `A;B`. This makes categories useless...

Plus, it keeps bugging and failing to connect.